# Python Array coin sort

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to do a coin sort python program using an array in python, wondering what the most efficient way was...
This is what I have so far, any help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
values = [50,20,10,5,1]    #values of coins
amount = int(input("how much change"))
remaining = amount
i = 0
fifty = 0
twenty = 0
ten = 0
five = 0
one = 0
print(remaining)
print("##########")
# while unsorted values remain:
# while len(values) >0:
while remaining >0:
  print(remaining)
  if remaining >= values[0]:
    remaining = remaining - values[0]
    fifty += 1
    # remaining = remaining - 50  
  
  if remaining >= 20 and remaining <50:
    remaining = remaining - values[1]
    twenty += 1
      # remaining = remaining - 20 
  if remaining >= 10 and remaining <20:
    remaining = remaining - values[2]
    ten += 1
  #  remaining = remaining - 10 
  if remaining >= 5 and remaining <10:
    remaining = remaining - values[3]
    five += 1 
  #  remaining = remaining - 5  
  if remaining >= 1 and remaining <5:
    remaining = remaining - values[4]
    one += 1 
      # remaining = remaining - 1 
  if remaining ==0:
    print("end loop")
    break
    
print("#########")
print("number of 50 coins = " + str(fifty))
print("number of 20 coins = " + str(twenty))
print("number of 10 coins = " + str(ten))
print("number of 5 coins = " + str(five))
print("number of 1p coins = " + str(one))
   
print("end")
  #i=i+1
```

I would like to have an efficient way to do this, Im teaching Computer Science.
Thanks

Comment: Could you try rewording your question so that you are asking about specific problems or with your implementation, rather than being more general?
See this guidance on asking about homework on stack overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2554826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `//` and `%` to build up a list of counts -- for each coin value, the integer division gives the number of coins used and then the remainder (`remaining % v`) is the new remaining count. Then loop through printing.  (Remove the `if count` condition if you want to show the zeros.)

```
values = [50,20,10,5,1]    #values of coins
amount = int(input("how much change "))
remaining = amount

counts = []
for v in values:
    counts.append(remaining // v)
    remaining %= v

for count, value in zip(counts, values):
    if count:
        print(f"number of {value} coins = {count}")
print("end")
```

Or if you are not interested in storing the output but only printing it, then you do not need to build a list:

```
values = [50,20,10,5,1]    #values of coins
amount = int(input("how much change "))
remaining = amount

for value in values:
    print(f"number of {value} coins = {remaining // value}")
    remaining %= value
print("end")
```